# How to Store an Image in Database and then Display it in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

How to store Image in Database and then retrieve and display it using MVC

I am Using MVC3, Entity Framework Database First, and SQL SERVER 2008

In Database I have used varbinary(MAX) for the Image

```
Image   varbinary(MAX)  Checked
```

Further I used

```
[DisplayName("Image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

in my mapping class

When I tried to save it in my Create action method

```
public ActionResult Create(MarjaaModel newMarjaa, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {                               
            newMarjaa.Image = new byte[uploadFile.ContentLength];
            uploadFile.InputStream.Read(newMarjaa.Image, 0, uploadFile.ContentLength);
        }
        try
        {
            data.submitMarjaa(newMarjaa);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I am successful in saving the image as binary data

But please tell me how I can retrieve this image and display it in my View

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Anything else you would like to ask? If not, you might want to show use [`what you have tried so far`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and explain what difficulties did you encounter with your code. Otherwise I really don't see how we could have any constructive discussion here.

Comment: It's possible but why would you store an image in a database? Store the link to the photo in the database and store the photo in a directory.

Comment: @War10ck , Dear I wana store Image in database

Comment: Com'on So Called Genius Intellectuals do a little more than negative voting. although i don't care about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I did it

A simple method in my controller

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(long id)
    {
        var model = data.getMarjaa(id);
        return File(model.Image, "image/jpg");
    }
```

and In my View

```
<td>
       @if (item.Image == null)
       {
       <img width="40" height="40" src="http://www.abc.com/images/staff/no_worry[1].jpg" />
       }
       else
       {
       <img width="40" height="40" src='@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Admin", new { id = item.id })' />
       }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<td>
               @{
                   var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.NewsImage);
                   var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);

            }
            <img src='@imgsrc' style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            </td>
```

only this need to view the pics